# Can i bind an error message to a TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I would like to bind a error message directly to a `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`. I cannot find a way to set the error through the layout. Is this even possible?

This is how I imagined it working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="error"
            type="String" />
    </data>
    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorText="@{error}">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</layout>
```

Comment: Use can read at: http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/tools/data-binding/guide.html . Get binding from activity, like: MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity); and set value by binding.setError("String you want")

Comment: Not really addressing the question. I know how to do basic binding already.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As of writing this answer (May 2016), there is no XML attribute corresponding to `setError()` method, so you cannot set error message directly in your XML, which is bit odd knowing `errorEnabled` is there. But this ommision can be easily fixed by creating [Binding Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) that would fill the gap and provide missing implementation. Something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:errorText")
public static void setErrorMessage(TextInputLayout view, String errorMessage) {
   view.setError(errorMessage);
}
```

See [official binding docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/vi/tools/data-binding/guide.html#attribute_setters), section "Attribute Setters" especially "Custom Setters".

---

**EDIT**

> Possibly dumb question, but where should i put this? Do I need to extend `TextInputLayout` and put this in there?

It's actually not a dumb question at all, simply because you cannot get complete answer by reading the official documentation. Luckily it is pretty simple: you do not need to extend anything - just put that method **anywhere** in your projects. You can create separate class (i.e. `DataBindingAdapters`) or just add this method to any existing class in your project - it does not really matter. As long as you annotate this method with `@BindingAdapter`, and ensure it is `public` **and** `static` it does not matter what class it lives in.

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but where should i put this? Do I need to extend TextInputLayout and put this in there?

Comment: Thank you sir for your guidance.

Comment: It definitely bugs me that there is no explicit registration for `@BindingAdapter` methods. They work basically anywhere in your code, and will be in a different place in every project.

Comment: @AustynMahoney Well, everything can be basically everywhere. Bigger problem is that i.e. 3rd party libraries can come with own `@BindingAdapter` and you cannot know that unless you step on problems it could generate being invoked instead of your adapters. Not sure registration would help much though.

Comment: Registration would at least give you some kind of order of operations, so it would solve the library `@BindingAdapter` issue.

Comment: @AustynMahoney There's always tradeof. Annotation based solutions are about simplification - doubt registration and all the stuff would be even close.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Could you please show how to set the errorText in the TextInputLayout? and any additional things I need to add to my build.gradle file unless I don't use data binding in my project? Basically I just want to set errorMessage in the xml

Comment: Cannot find the getter for attribute 'app:errorText' with value type java.lang.String on android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Answer (score 4):

I have made a binding like my answer on [How to set error on EditText using DataBinding Framwork MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286422/how-to-set-error-on-edittext-using-databinding-framwork-mvvm/39323789#39323789). But this time it used TextInputLayout as sample, like the previous one.

Purposes of this idea:

1. Make the xml as readable as possible and independent
2. Make the activity-side validation and xml-side validation independently

Of course, you can make you own validation and set it using the `<variable>` tag in xml

**First, implements the static binding method and the related String validation rules for preparation.**

Binding

```
  @BindingAdapter({"app:validation", "app:errorMsg"})
  public static void setErrorEnable(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, StringRule stringRule,
      final String errorMsg) {
  }
```

StringRule

```
  public static class Rule {

    public static StringRule NOT_EMPTY_RULE = s -> TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString());
    public static StringRule EMAIL_RULE = s -> s.toString().length() > 18;
  }

  public interface StringRule {

    boolean validate(Editable s);
  }
```

**Second, put the default validation and error message in the TextInputLayout and make it easy to know the validation, binding in xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/imageUrlValidation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:validation="@{Rule.NOT_EMPTY_RULE}"
      app:errorMsg='@{"Cannot be empty"}'
      >
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_imageUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Image Url"
        android:text="@={feedEntry.imageUrl}" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Thirdly, when the click button trigger, you can use the predefined id in TextInputLayout(e.g. imageUrlValidation)  to do the final validation on activity**

```
Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
          // TODO Do something
          //to trigger auto error enable
          FeedEntry inputFeedEntry = dialogFeedEntryBinding.getFeedEntry();
          Boolean[] validations = new Boolean[]{
              dialogFeedEntryBinding.imageUrlValidation.isErrorEnabled(),
              dialogFeedEntryBinding.titleValidation.isErrorEnabled(),
              dialogFeedEntryBinding.subTitleValidation.isErrorEnabled()
          };
          boolean isValid = true;
          for (Boolean validation : validations) {
            if (validation) {
              isValid = false;
            }
          }
          if (isValid) {
            new AsyncTask<FeedEntry, Void, Void>() {
              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(FeedEntry... feedEntries) {
                viewModel.insert(feedEntries);
                return null;
              }
            }.execute(inputFeedEntry);
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
          }
        });
```

The complete code is following:

**dialog_feedentry.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <data>

    <import type="com.example.common.components.TextInputEditTextBindingUtil.Rule" />

    <variable
      name="feedEntry"
      type="com.example.feedentry.repository.bean.FeedEntry" />

  </data>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/imageUrlValidation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:validation="@{Rule.NOT_EMPTY_RULE}"
      app:errorMsg='@{"Cannot be empty"}'
      >
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_imageUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Image Url"
        android:text="@={feedEntry.imageUrl}" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/titleValidation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:validation="@{Rule.NOT_EMPTY_RULE}"
      app:errorMsg='@{"Cannot be empty"}'
      >

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:text="@={feedEntry.title}"

        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/subTitleValidation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:validation="@{Rule.NOT_EMPTY_RULE}"
      app:errorMsg='@{"Cannot be empty"}'
      >

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Subtitle"
        android:text="@={feedEntry.subTitle}"

        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**TextInputEditTextBindingUtil.java**

```
package com.example.common.components;

import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

/**
 * Created by Charles Ng on 7/9/2017.
 */

public class TextInputEditTextBindingUtil {


  @BindingAdapter({"app:validation", "app:errorMsg"})
  public static void setErrorEnable(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, StringRule stringRule,
      final String errorMsg) {
    textInputLayout.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        textInputLayout
            .setErrorEnabled(stringRule.validate(textInputLayout.getEditText().getText()));
        if (stringRule.validate(textInputLayout.getEditText().getText())) {
          textInputLayout.setError(errorMsg);
        } else {
          textInputLayout.setError(null);
        }
      }
    });
    textInputLayout
        .setErrorEnabled(stringRule.validate(textInputLayout.getEditText().getText()));
    if (stringRule.validate(textInputLayout.getEditText().getText())) {
      textInputLayout.setError(errorMsg);
    } else {
      textInputLayout.setError(null);
    }
  }

  public static class Rule {

    public static StringRule NOT_EMPTY_RULE = s -> TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString());
    public static StringRule EMAIL_RULE = s -> s.toString().length() > 18;
  }

  public interface StringRule {

    boolean validate(Editable s);
  }

}
```

**FeedActivity.java**

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private FeedEntryListViewModel viewModel;

  @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
        .get(FeedEntryListViewModel.class);
    viewModel.init(this);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
      //insert sample data by button click
      final DialogFeedentryBinding dialogFeedEntryBinding = DataBindingUtil
          .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.dialog_feedentry, null, false);
      FeedEntry feedEntry = new FeedEntry("", "");
      feedEntry.setImageUrl("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png");
      dialogFeedEntryBinding.setFeedEntry(feedEntry);
      final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FeedActivity.this)
          .setTitle("Create a new Feed Entry")
          .setView(dialogFeedEntryBinding.getRoot())
          .setPositiveButton("Submit", null)
          .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss())
          .create();
      dialog.setOnShowListener(dialogInterface -> {
        Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
          // TODO Do something
          //to trigger auto error enable
          FeedEntry inputFeedEntry = dialogFeedEntryBinding.getFeedEntry();
          Boolean[] validations = new Boolean[]{
              dialogFeedEntryBinding.imageUrlValidation.isErrorEnabled(),
              dialogFeedEntryBinding.titleValidation.isErrorEnabled(),
              dialogFeedEntryBinding.subTitleValidation.isErrorEnabled()
          };
          boolean isValid = true;
          for (Boolean validation : validations) {
            if (validation) {
              isValid = false;
            }
          }
          if (isValid) {
            new AsyncTask<FeedEntry, Void, Void>() {
              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(FeedEntry... feedEntries) {
                viewModel.insert(feedEntries);
                return null;
              }
            }.execute(inputFeedEntry);
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
          }
        });
      });
      dialog.show();

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: kinda overkill for just a validation, do you have some simple.

Comment: In MVVM the binding shouldn't have any logic. The view controller should handle the validation.

Answer (score 4):

define your xml like this

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
            style="@style/myTextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            **app:errorEnabled="true"**
            **app:errorText="@{viewModel.emailErrorMessage}"**
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                **android:text="@={viewModel.emailText}" />**
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

then put this method anywhere

```
@BindingAdapter("app:errorText")
fun setErrorText(view: TextInputLayout, errorMessage: String) {
    if (errorMessage.isEmpty())
        view.error = null
    else
        view.error = errorMessage;
}
```

let's say you will make your validation after clicking on button so your button will be like this

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInButtonView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        **android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.logIn()}"**
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordTextInputLayout" />
```

then inside your view model

you will be having these

```
class SignInViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _emailErrorMessage = MutableLiveData("")
    val emailText = MutableLiveData("")    

    val emailErrorMessage: LiveData<String> = _emailErrorMessage

    fun logIn() {
        if (validateInput()) {

        }
    }

    private fun validateInput(): Boolean {
        if (emailText.value?.length!! < 5) {
            _emailErrorMessage.value = "no way"
            return false
        }
        _emailErrorMessage.value = ""
        return true

    }
.
.
```

and don't forget to add this in your activity or fragment

```
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

code is long so I added double asterisk on important lines