# How to display and clear error message for textinputlayout in android app using current architecture pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-edittext

I will develop a android app using current android app architecture(MVVM) in kotlin.I want to set an error message if user not enter username.
when user enter username and not enter password means already displayed username error message is cleared and display an error message for password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i bind an error message to a TextInputLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075871/can-i-bind-an-error-message-to-a-textinputlayout)

Comment: I don't get a solution to my problem.