# how to set error message below the textinputlayout in databinding using MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I want to  set error message below the textinput layout in databinding using MVVM in kotlin

will i was doing i encounter an error   : it shows null if the email edit text is empty , it should not do that

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this link: [Can i bind an error message to a TextInputLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075871/can-i-bind-an-error-message-to-a-textinputlayout/37076057)

In the second answer, you will see StringRule. By using that hopefully your problem will be fixed.

Comment: that link is not a perfect answer for this question